# How to test push notifications

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

How can I test-send push notification to only myself? If I send to everyone, over 14 000 will get the push message:

[image]

I want to test push on my device, because after I had to move the project to another project file, my device did not get the push message I sent earlier today.

So how can I test-send push to ONLY my device?

Comment: have you checked out the *"custom audience"*?

Comment: Yes, but how do i choose ONLY myself?

Comment: suscribe yourself to a channel and only send the push to that channel. You can do it manually searching your device on the dashboad, or programatically depending on your plataform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**luk2302**'s tutorial should work for you.

Something else you can check: In **Parse.com** on your left side, open up **App Settings** and then navigate to the **Push** tab:

[image]

Also double check that the keys in your `AppDelegate.swift` are the same as the once in the **Security & Keys** tab.

A tip for you is to follow this tutorial here about how to setup Push: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/PushTutorial/tree/master/iOS

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that is possible using the "old" dashboard, but can easily be achieved using the new one.

Therefore I would firstly recommend switching to the new dashboard (bottom left of the parse screen):

[image]

Then when creating a push message choose a custom audience and create a new one:

[image]

Then **Add a condition** and fill in the following:

- your platform, e.g. iOS
- `deviceToken` - `equals` - `%yourToken%`
- *save this audience* - **yes** + give it a useful name:

[image]

Comment: Where do i find deviceToken?

Comment: EDIT: OK i tried this, and it said Audience Size: 1 - But i did not get an notification.. And it also says: Pushes sent: 0. In Delivery Report it says: APNS - Invalid token
Invalid token, the user might have uninstalled the app.

Comment: @RoduckNickes are you sure you have entered the correct deviceToken? That exact method works for me.